# How to update one dictionary using the second dictionary for common words in between both the dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, dictionary

I am having trouble to get a target_sample.dict (a modified version of dictionary_1.dict), with the help of two dictionaries, as shown below-

**Step-1 need to find out the common English words between two dictionaries as mentioned below-**

**dictionary_1.dict** ---> **is in lowercase**
(it contains **Indonesian** and **English** words and its pronunciation lexicon)
Format- (dictionary_1.dict, contains thousands of words and lexicons as mentioned below)

1. aachen e e tS e n
2. aduk a d o k
3. aduk(2) a d u k
4. adult @ d a l t
5. adults @ d a l t s
6. advance e d v a n s

**dictionary_2.dict** ---> is in **UPPERCASE**
(it also contains only **English** word and its pronunciation lexicon)
Format- (dictionary_2.dict, also contains thousands of words and lexicons as mentioned below, similar to cmu-dictionary)

1. AACHEN AA K AH N
2. ADULTHOOD AE D AH L T HH UH D
3. ADULTS AE D AH L T S
4. ADULTS(2) AH D AH L T S
5. ADVANCE AH D V AE N S
6. ADVANCED AH D V AE N S T
7. ADVANCER AH D V AE N S ER

**Step-2** After finding the common English words between the dictionary_1.dict and dictioanry_2.dict, **there is a need to append the (common English words and its English pronunciation lexicon from dictionary_2.dict) to dictionary_1.dict**

**Also during this addition of common English word from dictionary_1.dict to dictionary_2.dict,
English word needs to be converted into the lowercase alphabet and append with (2)**

So ultimately the **target_sample.dict** will look like as mentioned below

**Desired format-**

1. aachen e e tS e n
2. aachen (2) AA K AH N
3. aduk a d o k
4. aduk(2) a d u k
5. adult @ d a l t
6. adults @ d a l t s
7. advance e d v a n s
8. advance (2) AH D V AE N S

As you can see the above-mentioned target_sample.dict, **it contains additionally** **(Which fulfils the requirement as mentioned in the step-2)**
- **aachen (2) AA K AH N** and
- **adavance (2) AH D V AE N S**

I tried a lot, to achieve the target_sample.dict, applied the logics like- importers-exporters, to find common words between two text files etc.

```
"""#!/usr/bin/env python"""
f1 = open("path to dictionary_1.dict", "r")
f2 = open("path to dictionary_2.dict", "r")
dict1_contents_list = f1.readlines() 
dict2_contents_list = f2.readlines() 
list3 = set(dict1_contents_list)&set(dict2_contents_list)
list4 = sorted(list3, key = lambda k : list1.index(k))
```

While executing the above code, it shows no error, that enhances the confusion? 
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: When you write questions, there is a live preview just under the editor. I cannot understand what you're asking here.

Comment: I am sorry for the unclear representation, I think now it is more clear

Answer (score 1):

You should start by placing the content of the english dictionary into an actual python dictionary, then you simply have to go through the indonesian one and add matching entries.

For example:

```
f1 = open("path to dictionary_1.dict", "r")
f2 = open("path to dictionary_2.dict", "r")
englishDict = { word.lower():speak for line in f2.readlines() for word,speak in [line.split(" ",1)] }
indoWords   = f1.readLines()
indoWords  += [ word+" (2) "+englishDict[word] for line in indoWords for word,_ in [line.split(" ",1)] if word in englishDict ]
indoWords   = sorted(indoWords)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a pandas dataframe and merge on the common words.

Comment: Can you explain it in more detail?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Can you please provide the sample code using the above example, that will be a great helpful. Thank You